# Как создать правило на ViPNet xfirewall?

Tags: консоль, firewall, vipnet

Доброе утро, тем кто не спит, начальство попросило удалить правила, потом говорят зачем вы их удалили, ну дураки. Обращаюсь к вам за помощью. Без понятия как их создавать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прекрасный справочник, тут всё нашёл
**ViPNet xFirewall 5
Справочник команд и конфигурационных
файлов**